# jQuery: Run animation after all calculations and DOM updates are complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I am trying to prevent an element from being animated until a specific function is complete. The problem is that the animation starts while the function still is running, so the animation is extremely laggy and jumpy instead of smooth and calm as it is when I disable the function.

My code looks something like this:

```
function editElement() {
    // Do a lot of calculations and edit what is inside #box (no Ajax)
}

$("#click").click(function() {
    editElement();
    $("#element").slideDown("slow");
});
```

How can force the `slideDown` animation to wait until the function is complete before running?

I have tried `callbacks` and `$.Deferred` suggested in other questions, but most of them seem to be directed towards Ajax and do not work for me. Thank you for your time!

Comment: is there any asynchronous operation in `editElement` like ajax requests

Comment: @Arun: No, only calculations and DOM edits.

Comment: `slideDown` is always executed after `editElement` has finished executing its code because JavaScript is a linear language. The only exception is when there are asynchronous functions inside, including AJAX and `setTimeout` / `setInterval`.

Comment: @totoro2 can you share the `editElement` method, is there any other animations there like `hide('slow')` `animate()` etc

Comment: @arun: The other jquery functions in `editElements` are `data()`, `remove()`, and `append()`. I am not sure if they count as animations.

Comment: @totoro2 without seeing what is happening inside we won't able to help you much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`slideDown` is always executed after `editElement` has finished executing its code because JavaScript is a "linear language". The only exception is when there are asynchronous functions inside, including AJAX and `setTimeout` / `setInterval`.

One suggestion though is that you can do this:

```
function ediElement(..., callback){
    //codes here....
    //Make sure there is no asynchronous functions.

    callback();
}

$("#click").click(function() {
    editElement(function(){
        $("#element").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you - I guess all I needed to know was that it was executed in a linear order. Then it must be because of the heavy elements inserted into the #element before animation that causes the lagg.